# JS files in one share project called by different solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a shared project, which called by two solutions. In this shared project, including a custom property to build with different resources (.js file):

```
<ItemGroup>    
   <Content Include="Scripts\ShareFolder\*.js" />    
   <Content Include=" Scripts \ShareFolderForSolution2\*.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My question is if there is a possibility to preset this custom property on a solution in Visual Studio, for example, if this shared project is called by other solution, the .js file in the ShareFolder should be build. If the project is called by solution2, the .js file in the ShareFolderForSolution2 should be used.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is if there is a possibility to preset this custom property on a solution in Visual Studio

You can use the property with condition for the `ItemGroup`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CustomPathForJsFile>ShareFolder</CustomPathForJsFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(SolutionName)' == 'Solution2'">
    <CustomPathForJsFile>ShareFolderForSolution2</CustomPathForJsFile>
</PropertyGroup>


<ItemGroup>
   <Content Condition="$(CustomPathForJsFile) == ''" Include="Scripts\ShareFolder\*.js" />
   <Content Condition="$(CustomPathForJsFile) != ''" Include=" Scripts \ ShareFolder ForSolution2\*.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

With this setting, only when your solution is `Solution2`, the .js file in the ShareFolderForSolution2 will be used.

Hope this helps.